# Upgrade has a problem

Tags: upgrade, apt, kernel, updates, dpkg

When I use: `sudo dpkg --configure  -a`,

I get this:

```
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.6-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
```

Then I type: `sudo apt-get -f install`

and the response is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calligra-l10n-engb cdparanoia k3b k3b-data k3b-i18n kde-l10n-engb
  kde-l10n-fa kde-l10n-zhcn kdevelop-l10n kdevelop-php-docs-l10n
  kdevelop-php-l10n language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-fa libflac++6
  libk3b6 libkcddb4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.6-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Finally, I use: `sudo sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/rsyslog.postinst configure`

and the response is

```
+ set -e
+ user_conf=/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
+ default_conf=/usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf
+ ucf --three-way --debconf-ok /usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

Then I try `sudo ucf --verbose --debug=2 --three-way --debconf-ok /{usr/share/rsyslog,etc/rsyslog.d}/50-default.conf`

and get:

```
ucf: The Debug value is 2
ucf: The new file is /usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf
ucf: The Destination file is /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
ucf: The Source directory is /usr/share/rsyslog
ucf: The State directory is /var/lib/ucf
The hash file exists
egrep [[:space:]]\/etc\/rsyslog\.d\/50\-default\.conf$ /var/lib/ucf/hashfile
80de10a8b9f13365de8cc4bbf8efec5e /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
The new start file is `/usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf\'
The destination is `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf\' (`\/etc\/rsyslog\.d\/50
\-default\.conf\')
The history is kept under \'/usr/share/rsyslog\'
The file may be cached at \'/var/lib/ucf/cache/:etc:rsyslog.d:50-default.conf\'
The destination file exists, and has md5sum:
80de10a8b9f13365de8cc4bbf8efec5e /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
The old md5sum exists, and is:
80de10a8b9f13365de8cc4bbf8efec5e
The new file exists, and has md5sum:
80de10a8b9f13365de8cc4bbf8efec5e /usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf
Historical md5sums are not available
ucf: The Debug value is 2
ucf: The new file is /usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf
ucf: The Destination file is /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
ucf: The Source directory is /usr/share/rsyslog
ucf: The State directory is /var/lib/ucf
The hash file exists
```

Then I type: `sudo apt-get upgrade -f`

and get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.6-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
rsyslog
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

If the error was transient, this will finish the installation. If the problem persists, please give us the full output of these commands.

If the error is the same, you can also run this command to get more info. Please add the full output to your post:

```
sudo sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/rsyslog.postinst configure
```

Comment: No, again I get this:

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rsyslog (5.8.6-1ubuntu9.1) ...
dpkg: error processing rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:

 rsyslog

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to add another command to run.

Comment: now, I get this

+ set -e

+ user_conf=/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

+ default_conf=/usr/share/rsyslog/50-default.conf

+ ucf --three-way --debconf-ok /usr/share/rsyslog

/50-default.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.con

Comment: Please add the full text to your question, not a comment. That makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop the rsyslog first**

```
 sudo service rsyslog stop
 sudo systemctl stop rsyslog.service
 sudo systemctl disable rsyslog.service
```

**Then Try:**

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```